# yield result from nested list dicts from based key values python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have list of dicts and each dict have nested list dicts. I need to yield result based on shot type and has children. I have written some piece of code but it's returning empty list.

```
data = [
    {
        'name': 'wdw show',
        'id': '12345',
        'parentId': None,
        'jobType': 'job',
        'has_children': True,
        'children': [
            {
                'name': 'wdw Scene1',
                'id': '123456',
                'parentId': '12345',
                'sceneType': 'scene',
                'has_children': True,
                'children': [
                    {
                        'name': 'wdw shot1',
                        'id': '23456',
                        'parentId': '123456',
                        'shotType': 'shot',
                        'has_children': True,
                        'children': [
                            {
                                'name': 'wdw task1',
                                'id': '0987',
                                'parentId': '23456',
                                'taskType': 'task',
                                'has_children': False,
                                'children': []
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        'name': 'wdw shot2',
                        'id': '23457',
                        'parentId': '123456',
                        'shotType': 'shot',
                        'has_children': True,
                        'children': [
                            {
                                'name': 'wdw task2',
                                'id': '0986',
                                'parentId': '23457',
                                'taskType': 'task',
                                'has_children': False,
                                'children': []
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                'name': 'wdw Scene2',
                'id': '123457',
                'parentId': '12345',
                'sceneType': 'scene',
                'has_children': True,
                'children': [
                    {
                        'name': 'wdw shot3',
                        'id': '3456',
                        'parentId': '123457',
                        'shotType': 'shot',
                        'has_children': False,
                        'children': []
                    },
                    {
                        'name': 'wdw shot4',
                        'id': '3457',
                        'parentId': '123457',
                        'shotType': 'shot',
                        'has_children': False,
                        'children': []
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                'name': 'wdw Scene3',
                'id': '123458',
                'parentId': '12345',
                'sceneType': 'scene',
                'has_children': True,
                'children': [
                    {
                        'name': 'wdw shot5',
                        'id': '456',
                        'parentId': '123458',
                        'shotType': 'shot',
                        'has_children': False,
                        'children': []
                    },
                    {
                        'name': 'wdw shot6',
                        'id': '457',
                        'parentId': '123458',
                        'shotType': 'shot',
                        'has_children': False,
                        'children': []
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

i am getting empty list, but I am expecting below result

```
Expected_data = [{'name': 'wdw show', 'id': '12345', 'parentId': None, 'jobType': 'job', 'has_children': True, 'children': [{'name': 'wdw Scene1', 'id': '123456', 'parentId': '12345', 'sceneType': 'scene', 'has_children': True, 'children': [{'name': 'wdw shot1', 'id': '23456','parentId': '123456', 'shotType': 'shot', 'has_children': True, 'children': [{'name': 'wdw task1', 'id': '0987', 'parentId': '23456', 'taskType': 'task', 'has_children': False, 'children': []}]}, {'name': 'wdw shot2', 'id': '23457', 'parentId': '123456', 'shotType': 'shot', 'has_children': True, 'children': [{'name': 'wdw task2', 'id': '0986', 'parentId': '23456', 'taskType': 'task', 'has_children': False, 'children': []}]}]}]}]
```

```
def filter_data(data):
    filtered_data = []
    for item in data:
        filtered_item = item.copy()
        children = item.get('children')
        if children:
            filtered_children = filter_data(children)
            if any(
                grandchild.get('shotType') == 'shot' and grandchild.get('has_children')
                for child in filtered_children
                for grandchild in child.get('children', [])
            ):
                filtered_item['children'].extend(filtered_children)  # Append the filtered_children list
                filtered_data.append(filtered_item)
    return filtered_data


expected_data = filter_data(data)
print(expected_data)
```

Comment: where are you using `yield`  ?

Comment: Where did you define what grandchild is? Looks like the 'if any' is broken or not doing what you expect it to do. Break it out into specific if's instead of trying to be clever with an any :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to apply two filters.

First, you want to filter for "grandchildren" who have children (great-grandchildren) and are type "shot". Having done that, you now want to filter for children who have children (grandchildren).

```py
import copy
import json

def filter_data(data):
    data2 = copy.deepcopy(data)
    filter_1 = lambda item: item["shotType"] == "shot" and item["children"]
    filter_2 = lambda item: bool(item["children"])
    for item in data2:
        for child in item["children"]:
            child["children"] = list(filter(filter_1, child["children"]))
        item["children"] = list(filter(filter_2, item["children"]))
    return data2

print(json.dumps(filter_data(data), indent=4))
```

If you correct the error in your expected data, this should produce a match.